# Bounding a Multivariate Normal probability

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, bounds, multivariate-distribution

I have $Z=(Z_1,...,Z_n)\tilde{}\mathcal{N}_n(\mu,\Sigma)$ where $\mu$ is all zeros and $\Sigma$ is a **non-negative** covariance with ones on the diagonal and $>=0$ elsewhere.
Denote $h(x)=P\Big((Z_1,...,Z_n)\geq(z_{1-x},...,z_{1-x})\Big)$, where $z_{1-x}$ is the $(1-x)$ quantile of normal distribution, i.e. $z_{1-x} = \Phi^{-1}(1-x)$. Recall the definition of convex function:
$$\forall\lambda\in[0,1]: h(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda h( x)+(1-\lambda)h(y)$$

I want to show that for every $a\in(0,1]$  and  $x\in[0,1]$ it holds that
$$h(ax)\leq ah(x)$$
, i.e. I want to show that $h(\cdot)$ is sub homogeneous/convex. Keep in mind that $h(\cdot)$ is monotonically increasing and $h(0)=0$, $h(1)=1$.

Any ideas? Thanks to the helpers :)

Remark: $x^n\leq h(x)\leq x$ is true since $\Sigma$ is non-negative (positive correlation).

In the graph below you can see $ah(x)$ - black line, and $h(ax)$ - red line, for a=0.5. [image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking: by "non-negative" do you mean *non-negative definite* or do you mean *all coefficients are non-negative*?

Comment: I mean the matrix is [non negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_matrix).

Comment: Thank you.  But now that you have substantially edited the question, it is important to explain what you mean by "$z_{1-x}$" and that you explain what "sub homogeneous" might be.

Comment: $z_{1-x}$ is the $(1-x)$ quantile of normal distribution, i.e. $z_{1-x} = \Phi^{-1}(1-x)$. A function is sub homogeneous if $h(ax)≤ah(x)$ which is a private case of convex.

Comment: I had to ask, because I was hoping you meant something else.  Assuming by "Normal distribution" you mean the *standard* normal distribution, what you want to prove doesn't even hold when $n=1$!  Test it for $\Sigma=(\sigma)$ with $\sigma \lt 1$.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a correlation matrix. it has ones on the diagonal and $=>0$ elsewhere